# MVP - как правильно перейти к другому контроллеру?

Tags: android, mvp

Использую в разработке приложений библиотеки mosby, mvp. Вопрос: где должен находиться код, который сменяет экраны, в контроллере или в презентере? Говорят, что в презентере. Тогда вопрос, почему в презентере нет метода getRouter(), тогда как в контроллере он есть?

Comment: Я так понял, не просто mosby, а mosby-conductor? Что Вам мешает передать роутер в презентер при выполнении действия пользователя, приводящего к смене экрана?

Comment: да, mosby-conductor. В общем-то, ничего не мешает, просто интересно, почему б не упросить пользователям библиотеки жизнь, реализовав этот метод в супер-классе презентера.

Comment: В этой библиотеке контроллер-обязательная часть для view. Это как активити или фрагмент - без него никуда. А презентер - опциональная, его используют везде по-разному: где-то выделяют всю логику экрана под него, где-то используют как мост, добавляя еще Interactor, а где-то вообще не понимают зачем он нужен. Здесь `getRouter()`, как `startActivity()` (доступен в корне экрана грубо говоря). Может кто-то захочет вообще выделить роутинг в другой класс (не контроллер или презентер). Также презентер может существовать, когда вью не атачена(тогда смысла в роутере, находящемся в презентере, никакого)